# Cannot find control with path: Angular 4

Tags: ionic3, angular4-forms

I have my form Builder like this:

```
  initForm() {
    return this.generalForm= this.formBuilder.group({
      startDate: [new Date().toISOString(),Validators.compose([Validators.required])],
      hour:this.formBuilder.array([
        this.formBuilder.group({startHour: [Validators.compose([Validators.required])]})
      ]),
      laboratory: this.formBuilder.group({id:[Validators.compose([Validators.required])]}),
    });
  }
```

At the html, I faced a problem presenting the form like i have on the component.

```
<div formArrayName="hour">
          <div *ngFor="let hour of generalForm.controls.hour.controls; let i=index">
            <div  [formGroupName]="i">
              <ion-item>
                <ion-label >Hour </ion-label>
                <ion-datetime displayFormat="HH:mm" formControlName="startHour"></ion-datetime>
              </ion-item>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
```

I tried this. I have this error:

```
 Cannot find control with path: 'hour -> 0 ->  startHour'
```

How can I resolve the problem ?

Comment: How do you access hour -> 0 -> startHour

Comment: What are you trying to do ?